# Differentiation for term in Parenthesis

Tags: derivatives

What is the derivative of $(4 - 9x^4)^{\frac{1}2}$?

My answer is $\frac{1}2(4 - 9x^4)^{-\frac{1}2}$

But the answer is $-18x^3(4-9x^4)^{-\frac{1}2}$

Why is my answer not correct?

Comment: Because $f(g(x))'=f'(g(x))g'(x)$.

Comment: Actually, the answer should be $\displaystyle -18x^3\left(4-9x^4\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$. As @MXYMXY noted, you need to multiply by inner derivative.

Comment: @Galc127 well spotted, fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that because of the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule), $(f(g(x)))'=f'(g(x))g'(x)$.

In this case $f(x)=\sqrt x$, $g(x)=4-9x^4$.

So the answer would be $\frac{1}2(4 - 9x^4)^{-\frac{1}2} \times (-36x^3)=-18x^3(4-9x^4)$ as $g'(x)$ is $-36x^3$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\left((4 - 9x^4)^{\frac{1}2}\right)'\overset{\text{chain rule}}{=}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{4-9x^4}}\cdot (-36x^3)=-\frac{18x^3}{\sqrt{4-9x^4}}=\color{red}{-18x^3(4-9x^4)^{-\frac{1}2}}$$